# PHP compatibility issues

Tags: php, php-5.2

I have updated the php version on our database so we can work some wordpress websites. since updating from PHP Version 5.2.1 to 5.2.17 we have had some issues with other services on our db.

So I'm woundering is PHP 5.2.17 backwards compatible with php 5.2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be compatible. 5.2.1 and 5.2.17 imply the first and seventeenth patch release (still the 5.2.x release family), respectively. Check the changelog: http://us.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

5.2.1-5.2.17 are mostly bug fixes and minor feature enhancements.

There are probably some subtle changes, so you will want to look through the summaries on that page of each release. Or at the very least search on the changelog page for the functions you are having problems with to see if there were any changes. Other than that, no, there shouldn't be any groundbreaking differences.